# MapBox tooltip disappears

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm modeling this example for map: http://bl.ocks.org/rsudekum/6039370

The tooltips for both layers in this example only appear once and then disappear after the user switches to the other layer.

How can I make the tooltips remain like in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/yhahn/4156545 ?

Which part of the JS makes it disappear?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `tooltips` on adding and removing `gridlayers` based on the map's `hasLayer` state.

```js
if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
    map.removeLayer(gridlayer);
    this.className = '';
} else {
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.addLayer(gridlayer);
    this.className = 'active';
}
```

Here's an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/geografa/5eb8ba62ee4cf5076a8f).